# Как вывести на экран содержимое вектора?

Tags: c++

В этом фрагменте программы я в силах вывести размерность вектора, но как вывести его содержимое?

```
typedef pair <double, double> point;
...
...
vector<point> hull = convexHull(points);

cout << (hull.size()) << endl;
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Примерно так:

```
for(auto p : hull)
    cout << "(" << p.first << "," << p.second << ")  ";
cout << endl;
```